# Use output from find command to then remove a specific directory

Tags: command-line, find, rm, command-substitution

When i run this find command:

```
find /html/car_images/inventory/ -type f -iname \*.jpg -mtime -4
```

i get output like this:

```
/html/car_images/inventory/16031/16031_06.jpg
/html/car_images/inventory/16117/16117_01.jpg
/html/car_images/inventory/16126/16126_01.jpg
/html/car_images/inventory/16115/16115_01.jpg
/html/car_images/inventory/16128/16128_02.jpg
/html/car_images/inventory/16128/16128_03.jpg
/html/car_images/inventory/16128/16128_04.jpg
```

My goal is to delete a "thumbnail" folder that exists in each of these directories (ie delete this folder:  **/html/car_images/inventory/16128/thumbnails/**   and also delete **/html/car_images/inventory/16115/thumbnails/**

I'm thinking perhaps of a script that takes each line of output from the above find command, then replaces " ***.jpg** " with "thumbnails" and adds as a prefix "rm -fr" such that i end up with this:

```
rm -fr /var/www/html/car_images/inventory/16115/thumbnails/
rm -fr /var/www/html/car_images/inventory/16128/thumbnails/
```

and so on...

Any ideas on how to do this?   (maybe using the -exec option of find and sed or cut?)

(another way to phrase my entire goal is, if a folder contains a .jpg file that is "younger" than X days, than delete the "thumbnails" folder, in its folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't have filenames with newline(s):

```
find /html/car_images/inventory/ -type f -iname \*.jpg -mtime -4 \
     -exec sh -c 'echo "${1%/*}"' _ {} \; | sort -u | \
          xargs -d $'\n' -I{} rm -r {}/thumbnails
```

- The parameter expansion, `${1%/*}` extracts the portion without the filename from each found entry
- `sort -u` sorts and then make the entries unique so that we don't have any duplicate
- `xargs -I{} rm -r {}/thumbnails` adds `thumbnails` at the end, and then remove the resultant directory

Comment: Wow, thanks for that really fast, great answer,  i think your code will do exactly my goal,  however to test it i changed the last line:  rm -r {}/thumbnails  to  echo {}/thumbnails   ... hoping to get a list (to test before running with rm -r) ,  now maybe this is due to my change, but it only 'echos' a single directory ,  not several.  is this because of the rm to echo change i made or would you code as is only remove a single directory (because it should be removing several depending upon the -mtime number)  tks

Comment: @JamesGaul Ooops, my bad. Muscle memory caught me, check the edited version.

Comment: wow, im just blown away by how quickly you came up with that initial answer!   it works great!  thank you!

Comment: @JamesGaul Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while read dir;
  do
    rm -r "$dir"/thumbnails;
done < <(while read file; do dirname "$file"; done < <(find /html/car_images/inventory/ -type f -iname \*.jpg -mtime -4) | sort -u)
```

This is completed using a process substitution inside a process substitution.

It finds files based on OP criteria, gets dirname of each jpg file in a while loop, sorts and removes duplicates (inspired by @heemayl), then reads that in a while loop to remove the thumbnail directory.